# How to add style in typescript using react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

i want to apply style to span tag using typescript in react. I have a label counter with value next to it. something like below

counter 0

I have a component Label like below,

```
interface Props {
    color?: string;
    size?: number;
}

const Label = styled.span<Props>`
    color: ${props => props.color || props.theme.colors.text};
`;
```

and in my other component i use the label like below,

```
render = () => {
    const count_var = 0;
    return (
         <div>
             <Label> counter </Label>
             <span style={{ color: counter === 0 ? 'red' : counter === 1 ? 'blue' : 'green' }}> 
                 {count_var} </span>
          </div>
    )
}
```

from the above code, as you see i have place count variable within span tag since want to add a class to the count variable based on its value. and the output for above code would be like below,

```
counter0
```

How can i use the Label component to apply style to counter variable based on its value...
    if count var is 0 then should be in color red
    if count var is 1 then should be in color blue
    if count var is > 1 then should be in color green

Also i need to have a space between counter text and its value like below

```
counter 0
```

I am new to using typescript and not sure how to use styles using it. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: well `counter` is not defined.. did you intend to use `count_var`? otherwise your code looks fine. or did I misread your question?

Comment: For the spcing part, you can add a non-breaking space  (`&nbsp;`) in your label, to ensure that there is a space after "counter". Alternatively, you can move the `span` inside the label, which should make the space after "counter" count (sorry for the pun).

Comment: @abondoa: thanks but instead of adding &nbsp; is there a way to apply it within the string like for example <span>some string + {' '} </span>... this gives error...but isnt there a prettier way to do it?

Comment: okay fixed it by using <span>{'  '}{count_var}</span>